# 'this' in call function when it is used in subclass with superclass

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble of understanding the word 'this' in call function when it is used in subclass with super class like this:

```
function Rectangle(w, h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}

Rectangle.prototype.area = function() { return this.width * this.height; }

function PositionedRectangle(x, y, w, h) {
    Rectangle.call(this, w, h);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

PositionedRectangle.prototype = new Rectangle();

delete PositionedRectangle.prototype.width;
delete PositionedRectangle.prototype.height;

PositionedRectangle.prototype.constructor = PositionedRectangle;

PositionedRectangle.prototype.contains = function(x, y) {
    return (x > this.x && x < this.x + this.width && 
            y > this.y && this.y + this.height);
}

var r = new PositionedRectangle(2, 2, 2, 2); 

document.write(r.contains(3, 3)); // 4
document.write("<br>" + r.area()); // 4

document.write("<br>" + r.x + ", " + r.y + ", " + r.width + ", " + r.height + "<br>"); // 2, 2, 2, 2

document.write(r instanceof PositionedRectangle && r instanceof Rectangle && r instanceof Object); // true
```

Now this part I don't understand:

```
Rectangle.call(this, w, h);
```

in PositionedRectangle class. What 'this' stands for? With what can I replace it so the code can work normally? 
I thought first 'this' is same as Rectangle and I tried to replace it with name Rectangle but it didn't work. Than I thought it's a PositionedRectangle subclass I tried to replaace it with PositionedRectangle.

I read that 'this' meaning depends on how it is called and I know the first argument in call function represents an object, but when the value of that object is 'this' I don't understand what that actually represents.

And I am still new in JavaScript as you can see.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The `this` which is the first parameter represents what will be the value of `this` when used within the function `Rectangle` that you are invoking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript call Parent constructor in the Child (prototypical inheritance) - How it works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018033/javascript-call-parent-constructor-in-the-child-prototypical-inheritance-how)

Comment: Stop thinking "subclass" and "superclass". Javascript does not have class-based inheritance, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)** is javascript function which calls or simply runs a function with the given context and arguments.

> **Q:** in PositionedRectangle class. What 'this' stands for?

**A:** it stands for the constructor of the function **PositionedRectangle**.

> **Q:** With what can I replace it so the code can work normally?

**A:** it is fairly confusing what you're trying to achieve as it seems just some unstructured function to me!

> **Q:** I thought first 'this' is same as Rectangle...

**A:** there is no subclass/superclass in javascript, `this` in the line `Rectangle.call(this, w, h);` refers to the context of **PositionedRectangle** you can read more about **context** and **this** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

> **Q:** ...but when the value of that object is 'this' I don't understand what that actually represents.

**A:** let me give you an example to make it easier for you to comprehend. Imagine and I repeat just *Imagine* you have two functions `a` and `b`. a's context refers to `c` and b's context refers to `d`

```
function a(){
    this; //refers to c
}
function b(){
    this; //refers to d
}
```

now if you call `b` in the `a` function with a's context like this:

```
function a(){
    b.call(this); //remember this refers to c in a function
}
```

you're changing the context of `b` from `d` to `c`, so if you return the context of `b`:

```
function b(){
    return this;
}
```

and get back to the whole picture again, you'll see the difference:

```
function a(){
    this; //refers to c
    this.bContext=b.call(this);
}
function b(){
    return this; //refers to d
}

b(); //returns d
a.bContext; //returns c
```

I know it's a bit confusing at first, but you'll get it over time so don't push it too hard.

Comment: I definitely need more time to fully understand this. I'll read more and try to find some other examples. I think I've understood a little bit of this, thanks to your post and previous comments. Thanks